# Trying to find a way to show images with my array

Tags: javascript

I'm making a small name generator, i have a button click and I'm just trying to figure out a way to have images show up as the button is being pressed with the name array i have

```
const heroNames = ["Batman", "Spider-Man", "Hulk", "Super-Man",
   "Wonder Woman", "Ant-Man", "Flash", "Thor", "Iron-Man"] 

const getRandomName = () =>  `${heroNames[
   Math.floor(Math.random() * heroNames.length)
                              ]}` 

const displayName = () => {
   document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = getRandomName()
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", displayName)

displayName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array of image sources as well to match with each name.

```
const heroNames = ["Batman", "Spider-Man", "Hulk"/*,...*/],
            heroImages = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/19/Batman_%28circa_2016%29.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/21/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_129-1.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Hulk_%28circa_2019%29.png"];
const displayName = () => {
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * heroNames.length);
    document.getElementById("generate").textContent = heroNames[idx];
  document.getElementById("heroImg").src = heroImages[idx];
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", displayName)
```

Demo:

```js
const heroNames = ["Batman", "Spider-Man", "Hulk"],
            heroImages = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/19/Batman_%28circa_2016%29.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/21/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_129-1.png", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Hulk_%28circa_2019%29.png"];
const displayName = () => {
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * heroNames.length);
    document.getElementById("generate").textContent = heroNames[idx];
  document.getElementById("heroImg").src = heroImages[idx];
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", displayName)
```

```html
<p id="generate">
</p>
<img id="heroImg">
<button id="btn">
Generate
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the display name function and have the sources in an object.

```
const heroNames = ["Batman", "Spider-Man", "Hulk", "Super-Man", "Wonder Woman", "Ant-Man", "Flash", "Thor", "Iron-Man"];

const sources = {
  "Batman": "bat.png",
  "spider-man": "spider.png"
};

const getRandomName = () => heroNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * heroNames.length)];

const displayName = () => {
  const name=getRandomName();
  document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById("imageElement").src = sources[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the value from your function

```js
const heroNames = ["Batman", "Spider-Man", "Hulk", "Super-Man", "Wonder Woman", "Ant-Man", "Flash", "Thor", "Iron-Man"];

const getRandomName = () => {


return heroNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * heroNames.length)]}

const displayName = () => {
document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = getRandomName()
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", displayName)

displayName()
```

```html
<button id='btn'>press</button>
<div id='generate'></div>
```